# Class has no member speak?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am just starting to learn about classes and i am trying to make a very simple code called cat.

In  my main, h, and cpp file it says the class "Cat" has no member "speak" looked for a possible solution for awhile now but cant find anything to help.
If i put void Cat::speak() in my h file it corrects the other two, but then it says "Qualified name is not allowed in member deceleration"
//Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

Cat jim;

jim.speak(); //CLASS "CAT" HAS NO MEMBER "SPEAK"

return 0;
}
```

//cat.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef CAT_H_
#define CAT_H_

class Cat {
public:
void::speak(); //THE GLOBAL SCOPE HAS NO SPEAK
};

#endif /*CAT_H_*/
```

//cat.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

void Cat::speak() {     //CLASS "CAT" HAS NO MEMBER "SPEAK"
cout << "Meow!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: in your header file, use `void speak();` instead of `void::speak();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void::speak(); //THE GLOBAL SCOPE HAS NO SPEAK`

It's interpreting this as `void ::speak()` where leading an identifier (a name) with `::` indicates to C++, "Look in the global scope of all names".  `::` is the "scope resolution operator"

In the header file, you should just use `void speak();` since C++ sees it inside your class declaration and hence knows it's part of the class.

Comment: Thank you apparently i am to slow to notice these details.

Comment: No problem, if it solved your issue, always be sure to mark it as an accepted answer with the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

How did it even try to compile this line: `void::speak();`?
What did you even mean by it? Method `speak()` inside `void` namespace? but `void` is a reserved typename. Moreover, why is it inside the class then?

As I can guess, you were trying to use `void speak();` instead.

Comment: yes i was, I thought it was a bigger problem turns out it was the smallest problem i could encounter. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`void::speak()`

I figured I would chime in on this answer. But the above line is your problem. Essentially, what you have asked the program to do is look in the scope of the `void` namespace. However, `void` is a reserved typename and to my knowledge, does not have a function named `speak()` in it.

This is the one of the problems with `using namespace std`. Usually, when you are using something from the standard library, take `string` for example, you will say, "I need to declare a string here, from the standard library. `std::string hello`, is a perfectly good example that states, "string belongs in the standard libraries scope." `using namespace std` is bad practice and you go fumbling around trying things like `void::speak()` which again, is asking to grab it from void's namespace.

That being said, in classes, the header file is commonly used to declare functions in which you will use later. In the `cpp` file, you are simply saying, I have a class `Cat` and from the scope of `Cat` I will be using the function `speak()`. So `speak()` belongs to the class `Cat` and is in the scope of `Cat`. Which is why in the `cpp` file, you call `void Cat::speak()`;

So in summary, you header file should be:

```
class Cat
{
  public:
    void speak(); // the class has a public function named speak.
};
```